# Is it possible to pass parameters to a GPIO interrupt on a CC1310 (or similar TI devices) using the TI SDK

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, gpio, texas-instruments

I need to pass a parameter (like an SPI handle for example) to a GPIO ISR (on a CC1310 or similar, using the TI SDK v4.20.XX. This version is not a requirment, just my current version, updating the SDK would be a viable option.).

This is possible in SPI ISRs via a

```
void      *arg;         /*!< Argument to be passed to the callback function */
```

parameter in the `SPI_Transaction` struct. The transaction struct containing the custom argument then gets passed to the ISR (along with the SPI handle).

```
typedef void (*SPI_CallbackFxn) (SPI_Handle handle, SPI_Transaction *transaction);
```

The typedef for the GPIO ISR looks like this:

```
typedef void (*GPIO_CallbackFxn)(uint_least8_t index);
```

`index` is just the ID of the pin which triggered the interrupt. Is it just not possible to pass custom parameters (without unreasonable effort like rewriting the SDK) or did I miss something somewhere?

If this is not possible, how do I get something like a device handle to the ISR??

Comment: Why would you need to pass a device handler to an ISR? Are you aware that a callback is a different thing than an ISR, even if the callback is called from an ISR? What stops you from implementing the ISR in a way to call registered callbacks?

Comment: To check a status or write a flag to anywhere outside the callback scope.

Comment: And how should the ISR (or the interrupt causing its call) know the value to hand over?

Comment: Well, you tell the ISR what value to hand over? See the example in the question or my answer.

Comment: Exactly. Did you already knew this? If so, what purpose has your question? You read the documentation, didn't you? ;-) Anyway, it is still open whether you know the difference between an ISR and a callback function. Is this the core of your issue? And that you don't know how to implement setting user arguments?

Comment: It _is_ a Q'n'A site, trying to maintain a level of quality. -- According to your comments I'm under the impression that you did already know the answer when you posted the question. And I don't see how this question is useful for others. I voted down because of all three common reasons: it does not _show_ research effort, is unclear, and not useful, at least in my eyes. -- Anyway, let's stop here. You might want to write the next questions less _interpretable_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that in the v4.20.XX version of the SDK that I had installed, this is not possible (via SDK).

Later versions of the SDK [added](https://dev.ti.com/tirex/explore/content/simplelink_cc13xx_cc26xx_sdk_6_40_00_13/docs/drivers/doxygen/html/_g_p_i_o_8h.html#ac852b7d77163b3aa4979e7fb13798844)

```c
void GPIO_setUserArg(uint_least8_t index, void *arg);
void *GPIO_getUserArg(uint_least8_t index);
```

functions to pass arbitrary arguments. They seem to be available from v5.XX onwards.

Comment: And I'm sure that there is a possibly local static collection, that you could implement yourself. ;-) See my hint at the question.

Comment: How does this answer the question? Did you change to v5.xx? Is this case really a simple matter of v4.20 does not provide it, but v5?

Comment: Yes, just changing to 6.XX solved the problem. Will update the question to reflect that 4.XX is NOT a requirement, just my current version. It also VERY PLAINLY answers the question "is this possible in the SDK in v4.20" (as per the original question) by saying "no its not possible in 4.20 using the SDK!!!"